# Apache: .htaccess vs vhost conf file for blocking URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, block

I need to block some uld URLs that are generating a lot of traffic in my web server (Apache). For example to block all the requests like https://example.com/xxxxxx/

I Can't do that with IPtables so I am using [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) with a rule in my .htaccess

That is still consuming a lot of resources and I am wondering if there is a better way to block the request before reaching Apache. Or another most efficient way to do it within Apache. For example, I heard that parsing .htaccess files consumes resources so not sure if using the vhost .conf file can help or it is really the same...

Any advice on how can I block requests using the URL?

Thank you experts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly distributed configuration files consume more load than a single, central and static configuration. But the differences are not like day and night. The issue with a distributed configuration is more the effort to keep the overview, to maintain it.

If you can keep those requests away from the http server at all you certainly will see more difference. You could consider using a frontend server. Something like nginx or HAProxy that acts as a gate keeper and only forwards those requests you actually want to respond to. This makes little sense on a single system though, you'd need two separate cloud services or even systems for that.

Comment: Thanks. Im evaluating to have an API Gateway with a Web Application Firewall. This will reduce the workload on apache.
Apart from that, Im testing the mod_security module. I can set rules based on URL but not sure about the improvement versus the .htaccess rules (mod_rewrite).

Answer (score -1):

The best approach would be to add something like this to your httpd / vhost.conf file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/xxxx$
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Every call to /xxxx would result in mod_rewrite to return a 403 response.
Make sure to place those rules into the according vhost  tag.

Comment: Sorry, but neither does this answer the explicit question about efficiency, nor does it point out an alternative approach. It only repeats the obvious, which the OP already knows, according to the question ("so I am using mod_rewrite with a rule in my .htaccess").

Comment: Don't put it into htaccess, put it into httpd / vhost conf to make it more performant. This is the only thing one can do.